# Magento 2.4.3 - How to show SKU on category page?

Tags: category, magento2.4, sku

Is there a way to make SKU show on the Category page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Pawan says, you must override template file in your custom theme:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{my-theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Then, you can show product SKU for example just after Product Name.

Look for this code:

```
<strong class="product name product-item-name">
    <a class="product-item-link" href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
        <?=/* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
    </a>
</strong>
```

Final result would be:

```
<strong class="product name product-item-name">
    <a class="product-item-link" href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
        <?=/* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
    </a>
</strong>
<p class="product-sku">
    <?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>
</p>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question if you do not mind. I'm trying to get it to say "SKU" in front of the SKU, but can't figure it out.

Comment: <p class="product-sku">
    <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('SKU: ')) ?><?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>
</p>

Comment: Thanks, it woks, however, it only works on one of the servers. We have 2 servers; for some reason, it does not work for the other one. They both use Porto theme.

Answer (score 1):

First override template file in theme, if it not exist.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{my-theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

in foreach loop add below code to get sku, where you want.

```
<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "for each loop"?

Comment: means where you have access to product object.you can add above code below product name as well.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not 100% sure what you mean. Could you please show me an example or something?